# Help naming a class that has a single public method called Execute()

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, oop, class-design

I have designed the following class that should work kind of like a method (usually the user will just run Execute()):

```
public abstract class ??? {
    protected bool hasFailed = false;
    protected bool hasRun = false;

    public bool HasFailed { get { return hasFailed; } }
    public bool HasRun { get { return hasRun; } }

    private void Restart() {
        hasFailed = false;
        hasRun = false;
    }

    public bool Execute() {
        ExecuteImplementation();
        bool returnValue = hasFailed;
        Restart();
        return returnValue;
    }

    protected abstract void ExecuteImplementation();        
}
```

My question is: how should I name this class? Runnable? Method(sounds awkward)?

Comment: Surely there's a C# class that already does pretty much what this does?

Comment: If there's one, I'd like to know its name! Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you want `Execute` to return *false* if `hasFailed == true`? Just seems a little counterintuitive to me...

Comment: IMHO all what should I name questions in this fashion should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming a class is all about a good design. You have to know which use cases this class will be part of, which responsibility it will take and what collaborations will this class take part in. Naming class without context can only do harm. Naming class after a pattern just because the pattern uses similar names is even worse, because it might confuse any reader who knows something about patterns, whcih is exactly opposite of what patterns try to achieve - name common decisions/solutions/designs/etc... Your class can be Runnable, Executable, Method, Procedure, Job, Worker, RestartableExecutor, Command, Block, Closure, Functor and virtually pretty much anything without further information.

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities:

- action
- command
- worker
- method

I like action, personally.

Comment: I don't like action, mainly because it conflicts with a pre-existing .NET Framework delegate (and one which is very heavily-used, to boot).

Comment: Yes, I like Action too, but as said by Aaronaught, it ends up being a bad choice as it conflicts with System.Action.

Comment: Command is the one for me, but I would call it better CommandBase as it is abstract

Answer (score 2):

I guess a good question to ask yourself would be *what* you are executing.  Then you might get an idea of what to name it.

For example, if you are executing a file and folder scan, you could name the class `FileAndFolderScan`.

```
FileAndFolderScan.Execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

It sure looks like a `Task` to me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) uses classes with an `Execute()` method. Is that more or less what you're trying to accomplish? I guess it's close enough for me; I would call it a Command or Worker or something similar.

Do you know about [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I know BackgroundWorker. But this has nothing to do with Threads. I just want to have a class that allows different implementations of its Execute() method. It must return a boolean value as result and in child classes it can also have different return values in the form of public getters in the class!

Comment: I think Command or Action (as JRL suggested) would suit you then.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework already has a class that does this (several, actually).  They're called [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx).

If it's really doing a lot more than just executing a method - performing error handling or that sort of thing - then name it for what it actually *does*, not how it's implemented.

If you absolutely *have* to implement a totally generic and abstract class that does nothing but encapsulate an arbitrary method and some sort of success/failure status (why?), then... task, worker, command, instruction, request, activity, etc... pick any of the above, they all mean pretty much the same thing in this context.

Comment: The thing is that child classes can be way more complex and besides returning success/failure I want to return additional information in the form of public properties.

Comment: @devoured: That's exactly the problem that `EventHandler`-derived classes and the event pattern are already intended to solve.  I don't see much of a use for this base class, but if you're sure you know what you're doing, then I offered a number of naming suggestions above.

Answer (score 1):

At my work we were stuck on .NET 2.0 for a while (pre-`Action` and `Func` delegates) and I had been using a bunch of overloaded generic delegates with the same signatures called `Runner` and `Returner`. Seems to me you could go with `Runner` and have a pretty clear self-describing class.

Alternately, why not just go with something like `Executable` or `Executor`?

Answer (score 1):

**Task**

Client code should look good with this.

```
//create instance of Task implementation
Task myTask = TaskFactory.CreateTask();

//Execute the task
myTask.Execute()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up using :)

Comment: @devoured: you might want select any of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it an [Executioner](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html). :)

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**
You already have several suggestions like "Task", "Process", "Job", even "Command".

**Complementary comments:**
Any object has a life cycle, a "start" operation, usually the constructor, a "finish" operation, usually a "Dispose" or destructor, and unleast a single main operation like your "Execute()", but there can be more.

In you code, the constructor or destructor are internally managed by your compiler, but sometimes do some other stuff like open and closing files.

You may want to learn more about the Command Design pattern, as mention by previous answers, it seems to fit your case.